# How to break up 2d art into triangles using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 2d, box2d, textures

I have 2d character art that will be mapped to a Box2d skeleton. The character's arm, for example, may be 2 physics rectangles connected with a joint at the elbow.  Each rectangle will have its own corresponding art sprite.  The art for the lower arm will not be completely rectangular.  It may be a rectangular png source, but there will be a lot of negative space where the arm isn't necessarily drawn.

My question is what is the best way to break up the 2d art into triangles? Should I treat all flat sprites as a simple rectangle made up of 2 triangles, leaving a lot of alpha space?  Or is it best to break up the shape into multiple triangles and try to match the actual shape (possibly with a triangle fan)?  What might be some of the advantages/disadvantages of each approach?  I will be updating the textures as various things happen to the character.

Here's an illustration of what I'm talking about:

[image: img]

(the red square is the physics shape, and the blue lines are possible triangle configurations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less geometry is usually better for performance (3rd from the left).

The "exact" triangulation (4th from the left) would be useful for high-fidelity collision-detection (lasers reflecting off a shiny asteroid?).

Be careful with frequent texture updates.  `glTexSubImage2d()` is the way to go.

If your GL implementation supports it you can do asynchronous uploads [using PBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not considering the actual art shapes for collision detection. That will probably all be done with the physics model.I suppose I was wondering if all that extra rendered alpha space would remove the benefit of the simplicity of the 2 triangle solution... especially when textures become less rectangular and more negative space is used. Something circular, like a meteor texture, would have a lot of negative space in the rectangular texture. Overlapping several of these alpha = 0 areas over one another would have to have some negative effect, right?

Comment: If you don't need actual alpha blending (which requires more memory bandwidth due to the added destination pixel read) you can get away with [alpha testing](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Alpha_test), which simply discards an incoming pixel if the alpha value is below a certain threshold.  Actually I think you can combine blending and alpha testing to get the best of both worlds: With a low threshold value pure-zero pixels are culled early (before blending) while still letting you do nice alpha fades at the edges of objects.

Comment: Great...that makes a lot of sense, and is very helpful.